# Shortening words within a string

Tags: python, strings

The function receives a string containing a sentence. Its goal is to shorten every word in it to a length of 4 characters until the string is shorter than 38 characters and return.

The 38 characters max length is mandatory and must be reached with the least amount of deletion possible.

Here is what I've done:

```
# reduces each word to a lenght of 4
def shorten_words(string):
    i = 0
    j = 0
    while(len(string) > 38 and i < len(string)):
         array = list(string)
         if(array[i] != ' ' and array[i] != '-'):
             j += 1
         else:
             j = 0
         if(j > 4):
             array[i] = ''
             i -= 1
         i += 1
         string = ''.join(array)
    return(string)
```

I feel like the list/join method is inefficient and would like to know how I could improve this function

Comment: The post says, "its goal is to shorten every word in it to a length of 4 characters" but if the string is 38 characters or shorter, then the code returns the string unchanged. Could you fix the description of the problem please?

Comment: @GarethRees this has been done, thanks for letting me know

Comment: What do you mean by "least amount of deletion" though? Is there a requirement that each word in the end should be as close in length as possible? If not the problem is much simpler.

Answer (score 2):

Some suggestions:

- **Naming** is really important. `string`, `array`, `i` and `j` are not descriptive. After reading the entire function I *think* they could be renamed `sentence`, `words`, `string_index` and `word_length`.
- There's no point in adding empty strings to the array - they aren't printed anyway.
- What is the significance of 38? If it's not significant it should be removed, if it is it should be named something like `max_result_length`.
- In Python `return` is a [simple statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html), which means its argument should not be put in parentheses.